# Why won't this C++ While loop work?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm simply trying to get the user to put in their name/age and verify if it's correct. If not then they get 4 tries before the program will abort. However my while loops don't loop, instead they just continue on to the next loop. I've tried a variation of things inside the while parenthesis `(op != 1) (!(op = 1))` etc.

```
int main() {
    system("Color 0A");
    string name;
    int age;
    int tries = 0;
    int op = 0;
    cout << "Hello User" << endl;
    Sleep(3000);
    while ((op != 1) && (tries < 4)) {
        name = entName(name);
        cout << "So your name is " << name << "?" << endl;
        cout << "Enter '1' for YES or '2' for NO. ";
        cin >> op;
        if (op == 1) {
            cout << "Perfect!";
        }           
        if (op == 2) {
            cout << "Please Try Again!";
            tries+ 1;
            }
        if (tries = 4) {
            //abort the program
        }   
    }
    int op2 = 0;
    int tries2 = 0;
    while ((op2 != 1) && (tries2 < 4)) {
        op2 = 3;
        age = entAge();
        cout << "So you are " << age << " years old?" << endl;
        while ((op2 != 1) && (op2 != 2)) {
            cout << "Enter '1' for YES or '2' for NO. ";
            cin >> op2;
            if (op2 == 1) {
                cout << "Perfect!\n";
            }
            if (op2 == 2) {
                cout << "Please Try Again!\n";
                tries2++;
            }
            if (tries2 = 4) {
                //abort the programhi
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly new to C++ so I'm sorry if it does have a simple answer. But anyway, I've been debugging this for over half an hour and I looked online for 20+ minutes.

Comment: You do understand `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison right?

Comment: "I've tried a variation of things inside the while parenthesis" - Programming by guessing is really not a good thing to do you know.

Comment: Enable all warnings on your compiler; they'll catch things like this. `-Wall -Wextra`, and `-Weverything` if you're using clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (tries = 4) {
            //abort the program
        }
```

Change this to

```
if (tries == 4) {
            //abort the program
        }
```

And

```
f (op == 2) {
            cout << "Please Try Again!";
            tries+= 1; // tries+ 1;
            }
```

You can increment value in C++ like this `tries+ 1;`. Either use `tries+= 1;` or `tries++;`

Comment: Wow..... Something that simple.. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`tries+ 1;` should be `tries += 1;` or `tries++;`

And,

```
if (tries = 4) {
    //abort the program
}
```

should be:

```
if (tries == 4) {
    //abort the program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program should look like this:

```
int main() 
{
    system("Color 0A");
    string name;
    int age;
    int tries = 0;
    int op = 0;
    cout << "Hello User" << endl;
    Sleep(3000);
    while ((op != 1) && (tries < 4)) {
        name = entName(name);
        cout << "So your name is " << name << "?" << endl;
        cout << "Enter '1' for YES or '2' for NO. ";
        cin >> op;
        if (op == 1) {
            cout << "Perfect!";
        }           
        if (op == 2) {
            cout << "Please Try Again!";
            tries+= 1;
        }
        if (tries == 4) {
            //abort the program
        }   
    }
    int op2 = 0;
    int tries2 = 0;
    while ((op2 != 1) && (tries2 < 4)) {
        op2 = 3;
        age = entAge();
        cout << "So you are " << age << " years old?" << endl;
        while ((op2 != 1) && (op2 != 2)) {
            cout << "Enter '1' for YES or '2' for NO. ";
            cin >> op2;
            if (op2 == 1) {
                cout << "Perfect!\n";
            }
            if (op2 == 2) {
                cout << "Please Try Again!\n";
                tries2++;
            }
            if (tries2 == 4) {
                //abort the programhi
            }
        }
}
```

You have forget to use `=` sign at multiple places. `tries = 4` should be `tries == 4` for comparing variable `tries` with numeric 4. `tries = 4` was reassigning the variable `tries` to four and your `while` loop was getting terminated after it's first run. Also, `tries + 1` should be `tries += 1` or `tries++` to increment the value of `tries` variable by one.